# Android firebase access for all app users

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I had configured firebase database for PUBLIC access during testing which worked fine. And now I wanted to change the setting so that only the app users are allowed to access. But now I get the read/write permission error while accessing from the app. Is there any update that needs to be included in the code accessing the database?

The changed in firebase rule:

```
{
  "rules": {
  ".read": "auth != null",
  ".write": "auth != null"
  }
}
```

Snippet of the code accessing the DB:

```
DatabaseReference mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(DBReference);

mDatabase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
```

Comment: Are you checking that the user is logged before trying to access to the database?
https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/manage-users

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you must use [Firebase Authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/start/) to authenticate users **before** starting any queries towards the database. Without a valid token, the queries will instantly fail and will not be automatically retried.

In practice, using an `AuthStateListener` at application startup is crucial. Start one early on, wait for it to return the current state: if there's a user, you can start using the database; if there's none, you need for example a login screen instead.

Comment: I have found the tutorial for Authentication separately. But what I am looking for is how to bridge the two? i.e how do I associate the instance received by authentication to the database reference? As shown in my below comments, first one retrieves the Database instance and second one retrieves Auth instance.

Comment: DatabaseReference mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(DBReference);

Comment: FirebaseAuth mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

Comment: You don't need to do anything like that yourself. It's automatic.